# Unable to navigate pdf in new tab of browser from Microsoft web chat bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework, web-chat

I am unable to open pdf in a new tab of browser by passing URL using `Attachment` in Web chat bot framework. My code snippet as below.

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
attachment.ContentType = "application/pdf";
attachment.ContentUrl = DocUrl;
attachment.Name = "Name";
var response = helper.CreateResponseWithSuggestions(valueDataState.suggessionReply, attachment);
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

-----In helper------

```
public Activity CreateResponseWithSuggestions(Activity SuggestionsActivity, Attachment attachment)
{
     var response = SuggestionsActivity;
     response.Attachments = new List<Attachment>() { attachment };
     return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, passing a PDF file as an attachment to the bot to then open in a new tab/window won't work. The Azure Bot Service allows for temporary hosting of files that are then available for download by others. The files are also only stored temporarily. It is not meant for hosting (storing) files to then be consumed as a link.

You will need to first store the file somewhere where you can then obtain a URL that links to it. And then, rather than sending an attachment you should send a hero card, or something similar, with a button that executes the `openUrl` action opening the link to the stored file. Review the [06.using-cards](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/06.using-cards) sample for information on setting up. You can also reference the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-add-media-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript#send-a-hero-card) for additional context.

```js
CardFactory.heroCard(
  'BotFramework Hero Card',
  CardFactory.images(['https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/7ff5/e07cfef0-aa3b-40bb-9baa-7c9ef8ff7ff5/buildreactionbotframework_960.jpg']),
  CardFactory.actions([
    {
      type: 'openUrl',
      title: 'Get started',
      value: 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/'
    }
  ])
);
```

Hope of help!

Comment: Your solution is really helpful to me. I achieved this functionality from the client side.